# jqgrid setFrozenColumns cellEdit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Did anybody find a solution to set frozen columns with editable grid?
In my project I have a grid with 2 fixed columns, they are not editable (titles).
Other columns are editable.

So setFrozenColumns makes no effect.

Does anybody know any solution?

yes, I know about the limitation:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns

That's why I ask you.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested in [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/frozen-column-impressions/#p25746) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FrozenMultiselectColumns.htm)) a workaround. It works not in all situations, but it's the best solution which I can suggest now:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! As always I'm very appreciate to you. After killing of editCell I have problem with autosubmit but I think now I can correct it myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one
It's possible to edit cell and inline editing with frozen column.Don't set frozen property at the time of creating grid.
    apply it after grid complete.

```
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid("setGridParam",{cellEdit : false});
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid("setGridParam",{multiSelect : false});
$("#gridid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter : true,
    beforeSearch: function(){
        //remove_onclick_property();
    }
});
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid('setColProp','columnname',{frozen:true});
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid("setGridParam",{cellEdit : true});
```

After it if alignment problems come apply padding to data.