# Can we edit frozen column in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid with inline edit and few frozen columns. I gathered some information on how to make this work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360981/jqgrid-setfrozencolumns-celledit). The answer in the link has a frozen column which is multi-select.
But what I wanted to know is if there is any way or a work around to edit a frozen column in inline edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure this one out for a little while now, and was finally able to come up with something that works for my situation.  Hopefully you can do something similar.

I created the following function to be called when the **edit** button is clicked:

```
var editRow = function(rowId) {
    $('#' + gridId).editRow(rowId);
    $('#' + gridId + '_frozen').editRow(rowId);
};
```

This will make the frozen columns appear editable to the user.

I created the following function to be called when the **save** button is clicked:

```
var saveRow = function(rowId) {
    $('#' + gridId + '_frozen' + ' #' + rowId + ' > td').each(function () {
        var col = $(this).attr('aria-describedby');
        $('#' + gridId + ' #' + rowId + ' > td[aria-describedby="' + col + '"]')
                .children(':first')
                .val($(this).children(':first').val());
    });
    $('#' + gridId).saveRow(rowId);
};
```

This code will take the value from the *frozen* cell and copy it to the underlying *hidden* cell - which is the cell whose value is submitted on save.

I also have a **cancel** option, which calls the following method:

```
var cancelRow = function(rowId) {
    $('#' + gridId).restoreRow(rowId);
    $('#' + gridId + '_frozen').restoreRow(rowId);
};
```

**UPDATE:**
I found that this solution only works in IE(8), not in Chrome or Firefox.  The web application I am working on only needs to be compatible with IE8, but I will try to find a solution for the other browsers as well.